# Why doesn't the program run the else block?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def maxdiff(x):
    i = 1
    max = x[0]
    min = x[0]
    while i < len(x):
        if x[i] > max:
            max = x[i]
        elif x[i] < min:
            min = x[i]
        else:
            continue
        i = i+1
    return max-min
```

If `x = [2,4,6,1,3,9]` the result should be 9-1 = 8. However, the function doesn't complete execution.

Debugging helped me understand that it doesn't execute the `else` statement. It directly jumps to `i=i+1`.

In this case, x[4] = 3 and it neither is greater than `max` and nor less than `min`. So, the function jumps back to while loop without incrementing `i`. Why does it happen?

Comment: It **does** execute the `else` branch, which causes an infinite loop,  as expected (`i` never changes so the `while` condition is never `False`)

Comment: So you just said it. It neither is greater nor lesser. So it runs `else` statement, because of the `continue` statement, `i` is not being incremented and this causes an infinite loop.

Comment: You don’t need the else: continue.  Just remove it.

Comment: Seems like a `for` loop would be the way to go here, or just `max(x) - min(x)` since these are builtin functions.

Comment: Just use builtin `max()` and `min()`. `maxdiff = max(x) - min(x)`.

Comment: Thanks all, this worked. However, while debugging (I use Visual studio code), I found that the statement is not passed even to the else function. Ideally, in a line by line execution, it should move to else and then move to continue and should probably then move back to while loop right?

Comment: Yes, continue will skip directly to the beginning of next loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're iterating over the values in your input array, you should restructure to use a for-loop:

```py
def maxdiff(x):
    max = x[0]
    min = x[0]
    for val in x[1:]:
        if val > max:
            max = val
        elif val < min:
            min = val

    return max-min
```

This not only ends up being cleaner but also reduces the risk of non-terminating loops.

**Alternatively**

You can always use the built-ins (of which there are [many](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)):

```py
def maxdiff(x):
    return max(x)-min(x)
```

Comment: Thanks. Does for loop auto increment?

Comment: @boonie Yes in Python it does.

Comment: It’s a good answer, but this would still be the way to approach this issue - rely on the built-ins.  maxdiff = max(x) - min(x)

Comment: @S3DEV I will add this to the answer, I was operating on the assumption that this was an exercise which was specifically asked to be solved using iteration.